# Passing variable from one function to another in same class?

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I'm trying to create a button that changes colors on click.

After digging around in an old Python book I haven't looked at in years, I've gotten to the point where I make the the button, but I can't figure out how to pass `i` into the second function so it increments and is then is reset to `0`.

I suppose I could just increment I on click in the first function, but now I'm annoyed and want to figure it out.

Instead of self.change_color I tried `change_color(i)`. That threw an error. Same with trying `self.change_color(i)`.

I'm not sure what to do at this point.

```
import tkinter

class joeGUI:
    def __init__(self):

        i = 0
        colorArray = ['blue','DarkGreen','red','yellow']

        self.main_window = tkinter.Tk()

        self.color_button = tkinter.Button(self.main_window,
                                           text = 'Click to Change Color',
                                           command = self.change_color,
                                           bg = colorArray[i])
        self.color_button.pack()
        tkinter.mainloop()

    def change_color(self):
        if (count < 3):
            count += 1
        else:
            count = 0
        return count;


joe_gui = joeGUI()
```

Comment: Save i in a class attribute and call change_color(self.i).

Comment: Store `i` as a class attribute (`self.i = 0`) and change the references of `count` to `self.i`.

Comment: comments 2 seconds apart :D :P

Comment: Thank y'all so much!

Comment: Is there any reason this has been tagged C?

Comment: @LuisMuñoz Please provide the comment as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Store `i` as a class attribute (`self.i = 0`) and change the references of `count` to `self.i`.